# VB.NET Regex Remove character except if it between '< >'

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to remove all newline (\n) in the text, except if it between '>' and '<'.

Example:

Input:

```
"test text \n another\n something\n <br>\n<p>new te\nxt\n etc..."
```

Excepted:

```
"test text  another something <br>\n<p>new text etc..."
```

First, I try this (VB.NET):

```
X = "[^>]\n[^<]"
Y = Regex.Replace(Text, X, "")
```

It almost work, but it remove the two adjacent character.

So I try this (VB.NET):

```
X = "(?<=[^>]\b)\n(?=\b[^<])"
Y = Regex.Replace(Text, X, "")
```

But it doesn't work...

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Dim text As String = "test text \n another\n something\n <br>\n<p>new te\nxt\n etc..."
Dim X As String = "((?<=[^>])\\n)|(\\n(?=[^<]))"
Dim Y As String = Regex.Replace(text, X, "")
```

**Explanation:**

The first part of the regular expression (`((?<=[^>])\\n)`) matches if the new line doesn't follow on the `>` character. The second part of the regular expression (`(\\n(?=[^<]))`) matches if the new line doesn't before the `<` character. On these two matches the new line get replaced by a empty string.

Comment: Explanation would be great so the OP knows why his isnt working... Like he doesnt need the `\b` assert position...

Comment: `"(?=[^>])\\n(?=[^<])"` = `"\\n(?=[^<])"`